# global statement isn't working, and I don't understand why

Tags: python, function, scope, global, local

I'm a beginner in this area and I'm having trouble finding the same cases to my question.
My code is like this:

```
def zerofunc(value):
      global g
      value = 0
g = 15
zerofunc(g)
print(g)
```

I set the g to global inside the function to produce 0 as the final result, but
it still prints out 15 instead of 0. Could anybody explain why the global statement is not working in this case, and what I should do to avoid the same mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function sets a variable named `value` to zero, leaving g untouched.  If you want to change, `g`, this code would do it:

```
def zerofunc(value):
      global g
      g = 0
g = 15
zerofunc(g)
print(g)
```

That being said, there doesn't appear to be a good reason to make `g` global; globals are generally discouraged.

Comment: But doesn't `zerofunc(g)` insert g in the function as the argument and replace 'value' with g, thereby setting g=0 at the third line? That's why I thought the code would work.....

Comment: in that case you want `def zerofunc(g):`